# Ignore the scripts for a specific page

Tags: javascript, html, disqus

I have been trying to make a blog in publii. And let's assume that I made a home page, a Contact Us page and an article page. So I have been trying to implement comments using Disqus. So for that, I have put the code below as custom HTML after every post.

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
    (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'https://websitenamehere.com/embed.js';
    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

So by default this script will run on every post I make, ie it won't run on the home page but will come on the contact us page and article page. I don't need it on the contact us page so is there any HTML code to ignore this footer on the contact us page only?

Comment: so check the window.location.pathname and see if it is one of those pages

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Like basically I am running a script globally so my question is, Is there any way to ignore the script for a specific page?

Comment: So you change the script and say `if (pathName !== 'X' && pathName !== 'y') { appendIt }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prevent this function to run if the path of the current page meets some criterias. For example, you could edit your script to that :

```js
if(
  !window.location.pathname.startsWith('/contact')
  &&
  !window.location.pathname.startsWith('/about-us')
){

(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'https://websitenamehere.com/embed.js';
    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();

}
```

Of course you should change `/contact` and `/about-us` to the urls used in your website !